# Azure DevOps Server get branch by folder name

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

Is it possible to get a branch by the path to its child folder? I tried the endpoint mentioned in the [Azure DevOps Server API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/branches/get?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0#get-a-branch-with-parents) `schema://host:port/tfs/Collection/Project/_apis/tfvc/branches?path=MyParentBranch/Services/MyChildBranch/GoldProj/Utilities/Interfaces/&api-version=5.0`, but it works only with exact path to a branch`path=MyParentBranch/Services/MyChildBranch`.

The problem is that my service usually gets the full path to some file within my branch (for example `MyParentBranch/Services/MyChildBranch/GoldProj/Utilities/Interfaces/IService.cs`), and I can't say from that path, what part is the path to the branch rather than to a specific `file/folder` in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently getting branch by path to specific file/folder is not supported yet. The rest api only supports getting branch with exact path to a branch.

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site, which is our main forum for product suggestions. After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it.

BTW, you can use [Branches-Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/branches/get%20branches?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0#get-a-list-of-root-branches-with-children) api to list your branches with children  branches to help determine which branch one specific file/folder(`IService.cs`) belongs to.